# Does an open-ended interval implementation exist for Java?

Tags: java, math, intervals

I've got a classification of certain values in different intervals. Most have the form [20-30], but some are of the form [30-infinite).

Is there an interval class you know of which can represent:

- an interval which is not closed on both sides (e.g. (0-5) or [0-5) )
- an interval which closes (or starts) on infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Time&Money](http://timeandmoney.sourceforge.net/) project seems to have Interval class that you need.

See these files in their svn: [interval package](http://timeandmoney.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/timeandmoney/timeandmoney/trunk/src/main/java/com/domainlanguage/intervals/).

Comment: Using that sounds expensive and time consuming.

Comment: Why do you think it's expensive?

Comment: @tpdi these few classes can just be copied if you mean including the whole library. It's under MIT license.

Answer (score 3):

The Apache-commons-lang project (http://commons.apache.org/lang/) contains classes dealing with ranges (like IntRange - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html). I'm not sure it covers all your needs, but it might be worth checking.

Comment: I've seen the ranges, but since they are type specific they are not so useful as the classes from the Time&Money library.

Comment: The [Apache 3 version of Range](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html) uses generics.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no library classes, but I recall rather trivially writing such classes.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might end up here, you can have a look at [Google Ranges](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained) which are exactly what was asked here.