# Java check if number in interval

Tags: java, range, intervals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does an open-ended interval implementation exist for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724575/does-an-open-ended-interval-implementation-exist-for-java)

i have an int variable and i'd like to check if it's value is in an interval [a,b]. I know it's a simple matter of using x>=a and x<=b or implementing a simple method which can do this, but i'd like to know if there is something already done. Searched in Math class, but i wasn't able to find one. It's not that important and not that big of an issue, but i'm curious if there is something like this, so i can use it instead of implementing my own :)

In all my coding i haven't come across a method like this. Maybe one of you java gurus have :)

Thanks.

Comment: are you really asking for a function that return bool = x>=a && x<=b? probably i did not understand the question

Comment: I'm not asking how to make it, just if there is something already implemented in Java :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this:

```
public static boolean intervallContains(int low, int high, int n) {
    return n >= low && n <= high;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather go for writing this method myself than including a third-party dependency :)